# how do I sort a list of objects (list of dictonaries) in javascript?

Tags: javascript, sorting

I really just want to sort this list of dictionaries (coming from Python world) or objects here.

```
{Rank: "1", PAX name: "Ito", Best time: "1:22:16", Age: "49", Total halves run: "1", …}
2: {Rank: "", PAX name: "Zook", Best time: "99:00:00", Age: "38", Total halves run: "", …}
3: {Rank: "", PAX name: "Pink", Best time: "99:00:00", Age: "49", Total halves run: "", …}
4: {Rank: "", PAX name: "Coxswain", Best time: "99:00:00", Age: "16", Total halves run: "", …}
5: {Rank: "3", PAX name: "Shake It", Best time: "1:29:53", Age: "33", Total halves run: "1", …}
6: {Rank: "", PAX name: "Fresh Prince", Best time: "99:00:00", Age: "29", Total halves run: "", …}
7: {Rank: "2", PAX name: "Sweats", Best time: "1:25:04", Age: "40", Total halves run: "1", …}
8: {Rank: "", PAX name: "Cardiac", Best time: "99:00:00", Age: "37", Total halves run: "", …}
9: {Rank: "", PAX name: "Dial Up", Best time: "99:00:00", Age: "32", Total halves run: "", …}
```

Basically I want to sort by the Best time.

I tried something like this->

```
       data.sort(function(a,b) {
           return a['Best time'] - b.['Best time']
        });
     
      console.log(data);
```

I get an error on the `[` not making sense so I am just stuck.... and too tired to think clearly anymore

[image]

Comment: What is the error message? You should always add the error message to the post.

Comment: You are also subtracting two strings which does not make and sense. `console.log("1:22:16" - "99:00:00")`

Comment: It should be `b['Best time']` instead of `b.['Best time']`

Comment: use `a['Best time'].padStart(8, '0').localeCompare(b['Best time'].padStart(8, '0'))`

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what is the format of your "best time"
But as I see Its type is a string and you can't act a string like a number or a date type.

My solution: convert the best-times to the smallest pieces (like seconds), So for example, if your format is hh:mm:ss you can have something like this:

```
const totalTime = ss + (mm * 60) + (hh * 3600)
```

and then compare them.

Also for deriving those numbers (hh, mm, ss) from the string in each iteration of the loop, you may want to use substring() function to choose the numeric part and parseInt() to convert it to a number